# Want to do crud operation separately ech for parent grid and child grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, crud, subgrid

```
$(function() {

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Student/GetStudents",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['StudentId', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Gender', 'Class'],
        colModel: [{
                key: true,
                hidden: true,
                name: 'StudentId',
                index: 'StudentId',
                editable: true
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'FirstName',
                index: 'FirstName',
                editable: true
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'LastName',
                index: 'LastName',
                editable: true
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'Gender',
                index: 'Gender',
                editable: true,
                edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    value: {
                        'M': 'Male',
                        'F': 'Female',
                        'N': 'None'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'Class',
                index: 'Class',
                editable: true,
                edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    value: {
                        '1': '1st Class',
                        '2': '2nd Class',
                        '3': '3rd Class',
                        '4': '4th Class',
                        '5': '5th Class'
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#jqControls'),
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'StudentId',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        subGrid: true,
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        multiSort: true,
        sortable: true,
        loadonce: true,
        additionalProperties: ['Class', 'ClassLang'],
        autoencode: true,
        cmTemplate: {
            autoResizable: true
        },
        autoresizeOnLoad: true,
        autowidth: true,
        autoResizing: {
            //resetWidthOrg: true,
            compact: true
        },
        caption: 'Students Records',
        emptyrecords: 'No Students Records are Available to Display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        multiselect: false,
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {

            var subgrid_table_id;
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
            jQuery("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>");
            jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                //url: "/Student/GetStudentsMarks?RowId=" + row_id,
                // data: { 'RowId': row_id },
                datatype: function(pdata) {
                    getDataSubGrid(pdata, row_id);
                },
                mtype: 'Get',
                colNames: ['Id', 'StudentId', 'SubjectId', 'Subject', 'Marks'],
                colModel: [{
                        key: true,
                        hidden: true,
                        align: "right",
                        name: 'Id',
                        index: 'Id',
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: true,
                        hidden: true,
                        align: "right",
                        name: 't.StudentsId.StudentId',
                        index: 't.StudentsId.StudentId',
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: true,
                        hidden: true,
                        align: "right",
                        name: 'SubjectId',
                        index: 'SubjectId',
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: false,
                        Name: 'Subject',
                        index: 'Subject',
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: 'select',
                        editoptions: {
                            value: {
                                '1': 'Maths',
                                '2': 'English',
                                '3': 'Physics'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        key: false,
                        name: 'Marks',
                        align: "right",
                        index: 'Marks',
                        editable: true
                    }
                ],
                pager: jQuery('#jqControlsSub'),
                height: '100%',
                rowNum: 20,
                sortname: 'StudentId',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                viewrecords: true

            }).navGrid('#jqControlsSub', {
                edit: true,
                add: true,
                del: true,
                search: true,
                refresh: true
            }, {
                zIndex: 100,
                url: '/Subjects/EditSub',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                afterComplete: function(response) {
                    if (response.responseText) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
                }
            }, {
                zIndex: 100,
                url: "/Subjects/CreateSub",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,

                afterComplete: function(response) {
                    if (response.responseText) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
                }
            }, {
                zIndex: 100,
                url: "/Subjects/DeleteSub",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterDelete: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                msg: "Are you sure you want to delete ... ? ",
                afterComplete: function(response) {
                    if (response.responseText) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    })

    function getDataSubGrid(pData, row_id) {
        gridId = "table_t";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/Student/GetStudentsMarks?RowId=" + row_id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                console.log(data);
                ReceivedClientData(JSON.parse(getMain(data)).rows);
            },
            error: function(data, textStatus) {
                alert('An error has occured retrieving data subgrid!');
            }
        });
    }

    function getMain(dObj) {
        if (dObj.hasOwnProperty('d'))
            return dObj.d;
        else
            return dObj;
    }
});


[HttpPost]
public string CreateSub(Models.StudentSubjectInfo Model) {
    DataContext.SchoolContext db = new DataContext.SchoolContext();
    string msg;
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.StudentSubjectInfos.Add(Model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            msg = "Saved Successfully";
        } else {
            msg = "Validation data not successfully";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
    }
    return msg;
}


public string EditSub(Models.StudentSubjectInfo Model) {
    DataContext.SchoolContext db = new DataContext.SchoolContext();
    string msg;
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.Entry(Model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            msg = "Saved Successfully";
        } else {
            msg = "Validation data not successfully";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
    }
    return msg;
}
```

### [HttpPost]

```
public string DeleteSub(int id) {
    try {
        if (id != 0) {
            using(DataContext.SchoolContext db = new DataContext.SchoolContext()) {
                Models.StudentSubjectInfo studentCourseInfo = db.StudentSubjectInfos.Find(id);
                db.StudentSubjectInfos.Remove(studentCourseInfo);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return "Deleted successfully";
            }
        } else {
            return "Validation data not successfully";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
    }
}

public JsonResult GetStudentsMarks(string sidx, string sort, int page, int rows, int RowId) {
    DataContext.SchoolContext db = new DataContext.SchoolContext();
    sort = (sort == null) ? "" : sort;
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;

    var StudentMarksList = db.StudentSubjectInfos.Where(x => x.StudentsId.StudentId == RowId).Select(
        t => new {
            Id = t.SubjectId,
                t.StudentsId.StudentId,
                SubjectId = t.Id,
                Subject = t.SubjectId.Name,
                t.Marks
        });

    int totalRecords = StudentMarksList.Count();
    var totalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling((float) totalRecords / (float) rows);
    if (sort.ToUpper() == "DESC") {
        StudentMarksList = StudentMarksList.OrderByDescending(t => t.Marks);
        StudentMarksList = StudentMarksList.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    } else {
        //StudentMarksList = StudentMarksList.OrderBy(t => t.StudentId);
        //StudentMarksList = StudentMarksList.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
    var jsonData = new {
        total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = StudentMarksList
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

want to perform crud in the [Here is the table / grid i want to add info abot the student in the main grid and want to perform the crud in the subgrid as well
    for their marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXPxs.png)
how to use GetStudentsMarks
function to bind the data in the subgrid ?
    how to use the ajax call in jquery subgrid and parse data and bind it in the subgrid
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- JS section

```
 $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "/Student/GetStudents",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: ['StudentId', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Gender', 'Class'],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'StudentId', index: 'StudentId', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'M': 'Male', 'F': 'Female', 'N': 'None' } } },
        { key: false, name: 'Class', index: 'Class', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { '1': '1st Class', '2': '2nd Class', '3': '3rd Class', '4': '4th Class', '5': '5th Class' } } }
        //{ key: false, hidden: true, name: 'Name', align: "right", index: 'Name', editable: true },
        //{ key: false, hidden: true, name: 'Marks', align: "right", index: 'Marks', editable: true }
    ],
    pager: jQuery('#jqControls'),
    rowNum: 10,
    sortname: 'StudentId',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    subGrid: true,   
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    multiSort: true,
    sortable: true,
    loadonce: true,
    additionalProperties: ['Class', 'ClassLang'],
    autoencode: true,
    cmTemplate: {
        autoResizable: true
    },
    autoresizeOnLoad: true,
    autowidth: true,
    autoResizing: {
        //resetWidthOrg: true,
        compact: true
    },
    caption: 'Students Records',
    emptyrecords: 'No Students Records are Available to Display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    multiselect: false,
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        // we pass two parameters
        // subgrid_id is a id of the div tag created within a table
        // the row_id is the id of the row
        // If we want to pass additional parameters to the url we can use
        // the method getRowData(row_id) - which returns associative array in type name-value
        // here we can easy construct the following
        var subgrid_table_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>");
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url: "/Student/GetStudentsMarks?row_id=" + row_id,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['Id','name','SubjectId' ,'Subject', 'Marks'],
            colModel: [
                { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: false },
                { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'StudentsId', index: 'StudentsId', editable: false },
                { key: false, name: 'SubjectId', align: "center", index: 'SubjectId', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 1: 'Maths', 2: 'English', 3: 'Physics' } } },
                { key: false, name: 'Name', align: "center", index: 'Name', editable: false },
                { key: false, name: 'Marks', align: "center", index: 'Marks', editable: true }
            ],
            pager: jQuery('#jqControlsSub'),
            height: '100%',
            rowNum: 20,
            sortname: 'StudentId',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            viewrecords: true,
            subGrid: false,
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            multiSort: true,
            sortable: true,
            loadonce: true,
            additionalProperties: ['Name', 'Name'],
            autoencode: true,
            cmTemplate: {
                autoResizable: true
            },
            autoresizeOnLoad: true,
            caption: 'Subject Records',
            emptyrecords: 'No Subject Records are Available to Display',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            }
        }).navGrid('#jqControlsSub', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },
            {
                zIndex: 100,
                url: '/Subjects/EditSub?Student_Id=' + row_id + "",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                afterComplete: function (response) {
                    if (response.responseText) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                zIndex: 100,
                url: "/Subjects/CreateSub?Student_Id=" + row_id + "",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                afterComplete: function (response) {
                    if (response.responseText) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                zIndex: 100,
                url: "/Subjects/DeleteSub",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterDelete: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                msg: "Are you sure you want to delete ... ? ",
                afterComplete: function (response) {
                    if (response.responseText) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    //subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
    //    var subgridTableId = subgridDivId + "_t";
    //    $("#" + subgridDivId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
    //    $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
    //        datatype: 'local',
    //        data: mySubgrids[rowId],
    //        colNames: ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'],
    //        colModel: [
    //            { name: 'c1', width: 100 },
    //            { name: 'c2', width: 100 },
    //            { name: 'c3', width: 100 }
    //        ]

    //});
    //}
}).navGrid('#jqControls', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: '/Student/Edit',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
                location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Student/Create",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
                location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Student/Delete",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        msg: "Are you sure you want to delete Student... ? ",
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
                location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

-- CS Section

```
public string CreateSub([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Models.StudentSubjectInfo Model, int Student_Id)

    {
        DataContext.SchoolContext db = new DataContext.SchoolContext();
        string msg;
        Model.StudentsId = Student_Id;
        var data = db.StudentSubjectInfos.Where(x => x.StudentsId == Model.StudentsId && x.SubjectId == Model.SubjectId).FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (data != null) {
                    msg = "This subject is already exist choose another";
                }
                else
                {
                    db.StudentSubjectInfos.Add(Model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Validation data not successfully";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }


    public string EditSub(Models.StudentSubjectInfo Model,int Student_Id)
    {
        DataContext.SchoolContext db = new DataContext.SchoolContext();
        string msg;
        Model.StudentsId = Student_Id;
        Model.Id = db.StudentSubjectInfos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StudentsId == Model.StudentsId && x.SubjectId == Model.SubjectId).Id;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var data = db.StudentSubjectInfos.Where(x => x.Id == Model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                data.Marks = Model.Marks;
                data.SubjectId = Model.SubjectId;
                db.SaveChanges();
                msg = "Updated Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Validation data not successfully";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string DeleteSub(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Id != 0)
            {
                using (DataContext.SchoolContext db = new DataContext.SchoolContext())
                {
                    Models.StudentSubjectInfo studentCourseInfo = db.StudentSubjectInfos.Find(Id);
                    db.StudentSubjectInfos.Remove(studentCourseInfo);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return "Deleted successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Validation data not successfully";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?